# Output of DB::select is different from raw query in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have a MariaDB query that I am using in my Laravel application and I would like it to return 7 columns. When I dump the resultant array with PHP it seems to only be returning 4. However when I take the same query and run it in the PhpMyAdmin SQL editor it returns all 7 exactly as I would expect.

Just wondered what might be causing Laravel to filter the results to only four columns, status, name, telephone number and description?

Thanks!

Laravel Query:

```
    $entries = DB::select('SELECT status, contacts.name, contacts.telephone_number, companies.name, roles.name, stages.description, actions.description FROM entries JOIN contacts ON entries.contact_id = contacts.id JOIN companies ON contacts.id = companies.contact_id JOIN roles ON companies.id = roles.company_id JOIN stages ON roles.id = stages.role_id JOIN actions ON stages.id = actions.stage_id');
```

[image: Query output in Laravel]

Query for PHPMyAdmin SQL Editor:

```
    SELECT status, contacts.name, contacts.telephone_number, companies.name, roles.name, stages.description, actions.description FROM entries JOIN contacts ON entries.contact_id = contacts.id JOIN companies ON contacts.id = companies.contact_id JOIN roles ON companies.id = roles.company_id JOIN stages ON roles.id = stages.role_id JOIN actions ON stages.id = actions.stage_id
```

[image: Query output in PHPMyAdmin]

Comment: that's not how you query using laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's the same result in both cases. they just use the same attribute so the result in eloquent override each other. use aliases to fix the issue

```sql
SELECT status, contacts.name as contact_name, contacts.telephone_number, companies.name as company_name, roles.name as role_name , stages.description, actions.description FROM entries JOIN contacts ON entries.contact_id = contacts.id JOIN companies ON contacts.id = companies.contact_id JOIN roles ON companies.id = roles.company_id JOIN stages ON roles.id = stages.role_id JOIN actions ON stages.id = actions.stage_id
```

Answer (score 1):

As @N69S answered, you should set aliases to avoid the override. Another thing tho, if you are using Laravel, eloquent is your friend:

```
$entries = DB::table('entries')
    ->join('contacts', 'entries.contact_id', '=', 'contacts.id')
    ->join('companies', 'contacts.id', '=', 'companies.contact_id')
    ->join('roles', 'companies.id', '=', 'roles.company_id')
    ->join('stages', 'roles.id', '=', 'stages.role_id')
    ->join('actions', 'stages.id', '=', 'actions.stage_id')
    ->select('status', 'contacts.name AS contact_name', 'contacts.telephone_number', 'companies.name AS company_name', 'roles.name AS role_name', 'stages.description AS stage_description', 'actions.description AS action_description')
    ->get();
```

A better approach will be using models and set relations.